# Woocommerce/WP product page does not properly work on mobile

Tags: php, css, wordpress, mobile, woocommerce

I am setting up a website for my new business, using Woocommerce Bookings on WordPress. 
Although most elements are working on desktop and some mobile devices, product pages don't properly display on some other mobile devices such as iOS devices, for instance.

Below is a screen capture of what should appear on a product page : that is person and date selectors + "add to cart" button.

**Screen capture 1:**
[image: screen capture 1]

However, on some devices here is what appears : selectors and Add To Cart button are hidden.

**Screen capture 2:**
[image: screen capture 2]

When I check the source code on mobile, there are "display : none" styling elements for these hidden elements. However, I can't figure out how to find the source file on which this rule is edited and how to override it so that all elements display, even on smaller screens.

A product test page would be this one : https://parisian-wanderings.com/product/test

Can you help me out on this problem, please?